# PouchDB 7.2.2 Update Document not persisted

Tags: pouchdb

I have tried updating a doc per this reference:  https://pouchdb.com/guides/updating-deleting.html, and according to the response at update time, it says the DB has been updated.

However, if I close the browser and re-load the database my edits are gone, and it has "reverted" my changes to rev "1.0", and rev "2.0" no longer exists.  Its as if the change is never persisted to the DB.

I used the code as it appears on that reference.  This is a "local" only Database, it is not backed by a remote database.  This is the use case for the current application I am developing.  There is no plan for this to be backed by a remote database.

I am using Chrome on Windows 10, the latest version of Chrome.

Can anyone help out with the issue?

Before I edit the document, it is located via a search.  That code is at the bottom of this post.

Here is the code I am using to update a document.  After updating it does return the "new" document in the "then" statement.

```
database.get(newdoc._id).then(function(doc){
        doc.title = newdoc.title;
        doc.label = newdoc.labels;
        doc.content =  newdoc.content;
        //** Save the document here
        return database.put(doc, function callback(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.error('Error updating doc: ' + doc);
                console.error(err);
            } else {
                console.log('Update Successful: ' + doc);
                console.log(result);
            }
        });
    }).then(function(){
        return database.get(newdoc._id, function(err, doc) {
            if (err) {
                console.error('Error getting document.');
                console.error(err);
            } else if (doc._rev === newdoc._rev) {
                console.log('Document revision never changed : ' + doc._rev);
            } else {
                console.log('Document saved, new revision = ' + doc._rev);
                loadTheDocument();
            }
        });
    });
```

However, when I try to load the "new" document via a search, I get:

bm5-edit.js:121 DOMException: Failed to execute 'transaction' on 'IDBDatabase': The database connection is closing.

```
var sel = {
    _id:{ $regex : "^" + itemid + "$" },
    label:{ $regex: ".*" },
    title:{ $regex: ".*" },
    content:{ $regex: ".*" }
};
var cfgAll = {
    selector: sel,
    use_index: 'all-fields'
};

try {
    database.find(cfgAll).then(function(result){
        var len = '' + result.docs.length;
        if (len === "1") {
            $.each(result.docs, function(index, value){
                rev = value._rev;
                original = new Bookmark(value);
                original.setForm();
            });
        } else {
            console.error('Found ' + len + ' results.  Should have found 1.');
        }
    }).catch(function(err){
        console.error('Error performing search');
        console.error(err);
    });    
} catch (err) {
    console.error('Error performing search');
    console.error(err);
}
```

This search is executed successfully BEFORE I edit the document, and fails with this error AFTER I edit the document.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem to get any help.  Linking to a pouchDB guide is not going to get anywhere.  Since it's pouchDB it's very easy to reproduce via a code snippet in your question.

Comment: A few observations: `$regex` [causes a full index scan](https://pouchdb.com/guides/mango-queries.html#further-reading);  further the regex `.*` matches everything except newlines - so that query is both needless and wildly resource intensive.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  The search functions as I expect it to and does find the specific entry I am looking for.  When I search to retrieve that item after the update in another tab, I get the previous revision.  But in the same tab when I try to retrieve the item I get the above mentioned exception. I have been fighting with  with this for a while, and I feel that this type of operation is so fundamental an operation it should be trivial, but it does not seem to be at all.